# How to turn off mysql errors from being displayed to screen in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, error-reporting

Even though error_reporting is set to 0, database errors are still being printed to screen. Is there a setting somewhere I can change to disable database error reporting? This is for CodeIgniter v1.6.x

**EDIT**: Re: Fixing errors - Um, yes. I want to fix the errors. I get error notices from my error log, not from what my visitors see printed to their screen. That helps no one, and hurts my system's security.

**EDIT 2**: Setting error_reporting to 0 does not affect CodeIgniter's built-in error logging class from writing to the error log.

Answer (score 65):

Found the answer:

In `config/database.php:`

```
// ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
```

so:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

... should disable.

Comment: I'm lazy and forgetful so do this `$db['default']['db_debug'] = (ENVIRONMENT == 'developement') ? TRUE : FALSE;`

Comment: `$db['default']['db_debug'] = ENVIRONMENT == 'developement';`

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Ian's answer, to temporarily disable the error messages:

```
$db_debug = $this->db->db_debug;
$this->db->db_debug = false;

// Do your sketchy stuff here

$this->db->db_debug = $db_debug;
```

Answer (score 6):

- You don't want to change
  error_reporting to 0, because that will
  also suppress errors from being
  logged.
- instead you should change
      display_errors to 0

This doesn't explain why you are
        getting errors displayed though,
        assuming error_reporting is actually
        0. Maybe the framework handles these errors

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the /errors/db_error.php file under the application directory - that is the template included for DB errors.

However, you should really just fix the errors.