# Codeigniter production environment showing errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my production server I have set the environment to 'production' in Codigniter's index.php file:

`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');`

The case statement below this looks to be doing the right thing also (I haven't changed it).

However PHP errors are still being displayed eg:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'laassad' in 'field list'
SELECT laassad FROM contents LIMIT 1
Filename: /home/something/public_html/mysite/somemorestuff.php
Line Number: 11
```

This is obviously unattractive, and a security risk. Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour and how I might fix it?

I am using 'CI_VERSION', '2.1.2'

Comment: You can modify the error page so that it does not display specific details. `application/errors/error_db.php`.

Comment: isn't it query issue instead of environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining your environment as production only suppresses PHP errors - this is a DB error.

See this thread for answer: [How to turn off mysql errors from being displayed to screen in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288559/how-to-turn-off-mysql-errors-from-being-displayed-to-screen-in-codeigniter)