# How can I handle Codeigniter's "Database error" in PHP upon failure to insert new row?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, insert

I'm using the codeigniter framework to implement a CRUD server for a mysql database. The following function inserts a new row in the "alarmstate" table in the db. Alarm states have three parameters:

(id, tag, description)

```
public function save($alarmstate){

    $this->db->set($this->_setalarmstate($alarmstate))->insert('alarmstate');

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1){
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }else{
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Tags must be unique, so, when I try to insert a new alarm state with an already existing tag, the database should not allow this to happen.

The problem is that, when attempting to insert a new row with an already-existing tag, the function is aborted and the client gets a complete html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Database Error</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        ....
```

I'd like the CRUD server to return "-1" when there's such an error, but I'm not being able to prevent the server from returning said html page. I've tried to use a "try/catch" structure. I've also tried to use prepared statements, but I'm getting an error saying that "prepare()" is not a defined method in the mysqli driver.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Whatever is going on in `$this->db` is entirely beyond our knowledge. That's not from the standard PHP library. As such, we don't know what it does or how you can alter it.

Comment: I'm using the codeigniter framework.

Comment: That's quite some crucial information to omit…

Comment: I've edited the post and added this info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288559/how-to-turn-off-mysql-errors-from-being-displayed-to-screen-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check for returned variable like below.

> ```
>     $result = $this->db->set($this->_setalarmstate($alarmstate))->insert('alarmstate');
>     if($result){
>         return $this->db->insert_id();
>     }else{
>         return -1;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Doesn't work. I keep getting the same error. Right after trying to insert the new row (with a tag number that violates the uniqueness constraint), the function is aborted and the client gets a response with the html page indicated in the initial post. The return statements are never executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually suppress error output to the screen by changing the setting in the `application/config/database.php`

`$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;`

Then handle the error by:

```
if ( ! $this->db->simple_query('SELECT `example_field` FROM `example_table`'))
{
    $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
}
```

`